# How do I properly annotate an export that is result of function call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, redux, flowtype

I'm working on porting my app to use Flow types.  I also use the Nuclide IDE which shows me my flow coverage.  I'm trying to get all my files to 100% coverage so I can have type-safe code.  I'm encountering a situation in which Nuclide shows that my code doesn't have type coverage, but I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
const ReduxWrapper = connect(mapState, mapEvents)(Component)
export default ReduxWrapper
```

Nuclide says that ReduxWrapper isn't covered by Flow.  Why is that, and how can I fix it?

**Other Notes:**

- I've created library definitions for react-redux which I can add to my question if someone wants to see them.
- I already tried several ways to type-annotate it, but they just led to errors.  I'm asking about my original problem instead of asking about the problems with what I've already tried to avoid the XY problem.
- This is the hardest question I've ever written on StackOverflow.  I like to distill and simplify things but I haven't been able to find a simpler piece of code that replicates my problem.  If you need more information to answer just leave a comment and I'll add it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [flow-typed library](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed) which will add to your project flowtype definitions of your dependencies.

Take a look here https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/react-redux_v4.x.x/flow_v0.30.x-/react-redux_v4.x.x.js